# Как изменить класс иконки у текущего дропдауна?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет у меня есть мини-задание.

Мне нужно изменить класс у иконки в дропдауне.
Проблема в том что меняется класс у всех дропдаунов.
Как сделать чтобы менялась текущая иконка у дропдауна, а все остальные не менялись.
Ссылка на мини -задание: 
https://jsbin.com/raqiwulewe/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не делать кардинальных правок в Вашем коде, то можно сделать вот так:

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const items = menu.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item');

items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", e => {
  // Текущее меню
  const currentMenu = item.querySelector(".dropdown-menu");
  // Находим все меню
  menu.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu').forEach(element => {
    const icon = element.parentNode.querySelector('i');
    if (element !== currentMenu) {
      // Схлопываем все меню, кроме текущего
      // И делаем правильную иконку
      element.classList.toggle("d-none", true);
      icon.classList.toggle("fa-minus", false);
      icon.classList.toggle("fa-plus", true);
    } else {
      // Переключаем текущее меню и его иконку
      element.classList.toggle("d-none");
      icon.classList.toggle("fa-minus");
      icon.classList.toggle("fa-plus");
    }
  });

}));
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="dropdown-item">
      <i class="fas fa-plus icon"></i>
      <span>Dropdown menu item</span>
      <div class="dropdown-menu d-none">
        <ul class="dropdown-list">
          <li>Dropdown item 1</li>
          <li>Dropdown item 2</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- / .dropdown-list -->
      </div>
      <!-- / .dropdown-menu -->
    </li>
    <!-- / .dropdown-item -->
    <li>
      <span>Menu item</span>
    </li>
    <!-- / li -->
    <li class="dropdown-item">
      <i class="fas fa-plus icon"></i>
      <span>Dropdown menu item 2</span>
      <div class="dropdown-menu d-none">
        <ul class="dropdown-list">
          <li>Second Dropdown item 1</li>
          <li>Second Dropdown item 2</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- / .dropdown-list -->
      </div>
      <!-- / .dropdown-menu -->
    </li>
    <!-- / .dropdown-item -->
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```